# Need help showing that $x^2 + bx + c$ with $b^2 - 4c < 0$ is irreducible

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

Using the following definition of irreducible:

An element $q$ in the ring of polynomials over the field of real polynomials $\mathbb R[x]$ is irreducible if, for all $a, b\in \mathbb R[x]$ s.t. $q = a * b$, $a$ is invertible OR $b$ is invertible, i.e. $a$ or $b$ is a scalar.

For our purposes assume all polynomials are monic.

So, I want to show that $f = x^2 + bx + c$ with $b^2 - 4c < 0$ is irreducible per this definition. We immediately know that there exists a root $\alpha$ that is complex. We also know that the complex conjugate of $\alpha$, $\bar\alpha$, is a root.

Case 1: If $\alpha = \bar\alpha$, then $0 = (x-\alpha) = (x-\alpha)^2 = f$

Case 2: If $\alpha \neq \bar\alpha$, then $0 = (x-\alpha)(x - \bar\alpha) = f$

This is where I am confused. Per this definition, for case 2, if $q = x^2 + bx + c$, and  $a = (x - \alpha)$,  and $b = (x - \bar\alpha)$, then $q = a * b$ and neither $a$ nor $b$ are invertible! Therefore, $f$ is not irreducible!

And for case 1, while $a = (x - \alpha)$ and $b = 1$ is clearly irreducible, I do not understand how $(x - \alpha)^2$ is irreducible, where $a = b = (x - \alpha)$! This definition of irreducibility does not specify whether $a$ may $= b$, so I assume that it may.

Can someone help me see what I am not seeing here?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  For reals $\mathbb R$, type `$\mathbb R$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $b^2-4c < 0$, the roots $\alpha$  and $\overline{\alpha}$ are not real, so $z - \alpha$ and $z - \overline{\alpha}$ are not in $\mathbb R[z]$.  You are factoring over $\mathbb R[z]$, not $\mathbb C[z]$.

Comment: Ok, so that makes sense. (x - α) and (x - αc) do not belong to $R[z]$.  But what about when $α = αc$? Then, $α$ is real, so $(x - α)^2 = f$, and my understanding of the definition leads me to see that this is not irreducible...

Comment: When the roots are real (and thus $b^2 - 4c \ge 0$), $f$ is indeed reducible.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. Forgot that a real root meant $b^2 - 4c >= 0$, thanks!